# find and extract data from one table and insert it into another in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a sales system and I want to know the cost of a product through its code / id.
The part of uploading all the data of a product is fine, but I want to know the cost and that cost to introduce it to another table.

THIS IS IN THE PRODUCT TABLE:

```
CODE         NAME         COST   PRICE
44730        doritos        1    2
447390       ice            4    6
```

As an example I want to know what is the cost of the product with the code 44730, for that I have to use the following :

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_midatabase");

$cost = mysqli_query($db, "
SELECT cost FROM product WHERE code=44730
");
```

Now that same data that in theory should be 1 I want to introduce it in another table that should do this:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO myothertable (cost) VALUES ('$cost')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

and there is my mistake and it is that simply if you add something to the database but the data is 0, someone who helps me solve this problem please I would appreciate it

Comment: `$cost` is a query result. You need to parse that result to get (e.g.) `$cost['cost']`. Every single basic, introductory book or tutorial on PHP and MySQL covers this. And see about sql injection too!

Comment: But note that your first query is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single INSERT/SELECT query

```
INSERT INTO myothertable (cost) 
SELECT cost FROM product 
WHERE code=44730
```